# Attribute Routing not working with two or more controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have used attribute routing and set a RoutePrefix() as the default route of FirstController. Then i have created a new controller and gave its default route.

A runtime System.ArgumentException is generating on "GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);" in Global.asax showing Message:

> "A path segment cannot contain two consecutive parameters. They must
>   be separated by a '/' or by a literal string."

This is FirstController.cs

```
     [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/First")]
 public class FirstController : ApiController
 {
     [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
     [System.Web.Http.Route("Method1/{Param1}/{Param2}")]
     public int Method1(string Param1, string Param2)
     {
       //
     }
     [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
     [System.Web.Http.Route("Method2/{Param1}/{Param2}")]
     public int Method2(string Param1, string Param2)
     {
       //
     }
 }
```

This is SecondController.cs

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/Second")]
 public class SecondController : ApiController
 {
     [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
     [System.Web.Http.Route("Method3/{Param1}/{Param2}")]
     public int Method3(string Param1, string Param2)
     {
       //
     }
     [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
     [System.Web.Http.Route("Method4/{Param1}/{Param2}")]
     public int Method4(string Param1, string Param2)
     {
       //
     }
 }
```

And this is my Global.asax (returning data in JSON)

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

I'm trying to create multiple controllers having their own default routes. Please help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is a compile time error and not a runtime exception?

Comment: No, its a runtime error. By mistake i've wrote that. Pardon me..! Thnx

Comment: So there's actually nothing from with what you have posted, can you post the actual method signature that you are using?

Comment: Why i need to post the actual method signature? I've described the full problem scenario.

Comment: Yes, but if you take this code that you have shown us, it does NOT generate any errors. So you are doing something different in your real code. Until we see that, nobody can help you.

Comment: Check your actual code for typos as your current example will not produce the exception message stated in your post. A route like `MethodName/{Param1}{Param2}` will cause that error. Otherwise please provide a [mcve] so others can reproduce your issue and provide assistance

Comment: Your edit *still* doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message shown is normally associated with a route template like

```
Route("{Param1}{Param2}/{Param3})
```

where there is nothing separating two consecutive parameters like between `{Param1}{Param2}` in the above example. The framework will not be able to use such templates to match routes as it will not be able to identify which parameters to map to actions regardless of parameter name.

Check your route templates for typos as it is very easy to make this kind of mistake.

Try searching for `}{` in your code if you cannot easily identify it on sight.

Comment: There is no route like {Param1}{Param2} in code. All parameters are separated by /.

Comment: @PriyankMittal Are you going to show us some real code so you can be helped or just pretend that your example above is enough to diagnose?